# EPiServer 6 R2 All page types are available

Tags: episerver

Is there a way to force this checkbox to be unchecked at all times?

Whenever I uncheck it and then save the page type it auto-reset itself and automatically selects/check the checkbox once I edit the page type again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If that one is unchecked you need at least one page type checked in the list below.

If it's a page type that shouldn't have children a trick commonly used is to have a "dummy" page type that you set as available and on that page type you set that only a Role that no one has is allowed to use it for new pages.

Comment: Or even better & easier - to have this "DeadEnd" page type with unchecked "Available in edit mode"

Comment: I vaguely recall I had some problems with "Available in edit mode" set to false in some version/situation but of course that should give the same result.

Comment: "Available in edit mode" sounds like a good alternative. EPi7 has the same issue?